# F# Winforms ChartArea: "How to add ArrowStyle to the Axes"

Tags: winforms, charts, f#

I am in the process of making a chart and i want to add the `ArrowStyle` to the `axes`.

I have tried something like this:

```
let chartArea = new ChartArea("Hello")
chartArea.AxisX.ArrowStyle
```

Nothing Erors but nothing happens either. I just get a regular chart.

here is a reference to the [ArrowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.arrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property

can someone tell me how to add this `ArrowStyle` correctly to the `ChartArea` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set the `ArrowStyle` property using the `<-` operator like so:

```
let chartArea = new ChartArea("Hello")
chartArea.AxisX.ArrowStyle <- AxisArrowStyle.Triangle
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)
```

Comment: Thanks again Stuart!